# Python Docx - how to number headings?

Tags: python, python-docx

There is a good [example](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for Python Docx.

I have used multiple `document.add_heading('xxx', level=Y)` and can see when I open the generated document in MS Word that the levels are correct.

What I don't see is numbering, such a 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, etc I just see the heading text.

How can I display heading numbers, using Docx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alphanumeric heading prefixes are automatically created based on the outline style and level of the heading. Set the outline style and insert the correct level and you will get the numbering.

From documentation:

> _NumberingStyle objects class docx.styles.style._NumberingStyle[source] A numbering style. Not yet
> implemented.

However, if you set the heading like this:

`paragraph.style = document.styles['Heading 1']`

then it should default to the latent numbering style of that heading.

Comment: Hi,
what if I don´t want any numbering? 
By default it´s adding it
Thanks
Ester

Answer (score 2):

There is a great work around with python docx for achieving complex operations like headings enumerations. Here how to proceed:

1. Create a new blank document in Word and define your complex individual multilevel list there .
2. Save the blank document as `my_template.docx`.
3. Create the document in your python script based on your template:

```
    from docx import Document

    document = Document("my_template.docx")
    document.add_heading('My first numbered heading', level=1)
```

And, voila, you can generate your perfect document with numbered headings.

Comment: That is a brilliant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks you. In fact that's the way I work with it. Unfortunately there is no active community like we have with xslt writer to bring it to a version 1.0. So these kind of work arounds are essential.

Answer (score 0):

this answer will realy help you

first you need to new a without number header like this

```
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.style = document.styles['Heading 4']
```

then you will have xml word like this

```
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="4"/>
</w:pPr>
```

then you can access xml word "pStyle" property and change it using under code

```
header._p.pPr.pStyle.set(qn('w:val'), u'4FDD')
```

final, open word file you will get what you want !!!

Comment: I made this code trying to do what you said but I can't set pSyle because is None.

from docx import Document

document = Document()

document.add_heading("Hi !", level=1)

element = document.styles["Heading 1"].element
print(element.pPr.pStyle)  # got None

Answer (score -1):

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.nivel == 1: 
        return str(Level.count_1)+'.- '+self.titulo
    elif self.nivel==2: #Imprime si es del nivel 2
        return str(Level.count_1)+'.'+str(Level.count_2)+'.- '+self.titulo
    elif self.nivel==3: #Imprime si es del nivel 3
        return str(Level.count_1)+'.'+str(Level.count_2)+'.'+str(Level.count_3)+'.- '+self.titulo
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This is enumeration of titles (hard coded) not style based enumeration.